# How do I terminate windows directly from window choice mode in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to go into window choice mode (prefix-w) and then be able to kill windows without choosing them (hitting the Enter key).

Is this possible without configuration changes?

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

1) No

2) Yes

Add this to your .tmux.conf

```
bind e choose-window "kill-window -t %%"
```

now press (prefix e) will let you kill it